# Australian Geographical Data - simple format (perhaps WKT)

Tags: jts

I'm looking for some data on Australian boundaries - particularly the national boundary and individual state boundaries.  The format I would prefer is WKT but anything simple would be good (ideally I need to use it with the JTS (Java Topological Suite) package).

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if what you're after specifically is available, but here are a couple of good places to try:

- ['Geography' category](http://data.australia.gov.au/catalogue/geography) on [data.australia](http://data.australia.gov.au/)
- [Geoscience Australia](http://www.ga.gov.au/)